# Repair Outlook 2007 OST File

Tags: email, email-server

Previous versions of Outlook had the Inbox Repair Tool, which allows you to repair OST/PST files. Currently, I am using a Windows Vista and Office 2007 computer. I need to repair my OST file. It doesn't look like the Inbox Repair Tool is included with Office 2007.

Is there a newer version of the Inbox Repair Tool, or a similar Microsoft Tool, which will allow me to repair my OST file? If so, please send me the download link.

Thank

Comment: OST? Just delete or rename that file. It will repopulate itself.
(**O** ST, not **P** ST)

Comment: I am locking this to prevent Outlook repair tool spammers from even posting comments.